# fire event in actionscript on swf load?

Tags: events, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to get a bit of content to load on pageLoad instead of as a clickable event (but still keep the clickable event on the menu).

Here's the actionscript:

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;

/**
 * This is the menu that comes up at the bottom with various analysis and navigation options when a thumbnail is selected.
 */
class imagegal.BottomMenu extends MovieClip
{

public var bg_mc:MovieClip;
public var btns1_mc:MovieClip;

public function BottomMenu() 
{

    btns1_mc.prev_mc.label_txt.text = "PREVIOUS IMAGE"

    btns1_mc.next_mc.label_txt.text = "NEXT IMAGE";

    btns1_mc.info_mc.label_txt.text = "INFO";

    btns1_mc.thumbs_mc.label_txt.text = "THUMBNAILS";

    btns1_mc.menu_mc.label_txt.text = "MAIN MENU";

    btns1_mc.prev_mc.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
        _parent.loadPrevious();
    });

    btns1_mc.next_mc.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
        _parent.loadNext();
    });

    btns1_mc.info_mc.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
        _parent.toggleInfo();
    });

    btns1_mc.thumbs_mc.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
        _parent.showThumbs();
    });

    btns1_mc.menu_mc.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, function() {
        _parent.showMenu();
    });
}

public function resize(w:Number) {
    //mask_mc._width = w;
    //bg_mc._width = w;
}

}
```

The _parent.toggleInfo() function has the content i want displayed.  My question is, when this the corresponding as file is fired by the SWF, can i have that function fire?

Comment: Hm english-wise I just don't get it. "when this the corresponding as file is fired by the SWF, can i have that function fire?".

Comment: I suppose i could have been more clear:

I'm trying to get a function to happen automatically when that 'page' is loaded.  So if i'm looking at a gallery and there's a menu button that when clicked, shows a blurb about the image; that's what i'm talking about.  Is there a way to modify that so that the info box is displayed immediately? within the constructor, perhaps?  Forgive my newbness on this one, i'm not familiar with flash and got dumped with the project. You can see what i'm talking about here: http://wbrint.com/#/portraits/cat1/4/  Click the info button.

Comment: Just noting that you've tagged this [actionscript-3], but your code is AS2

Answer (score -1):

You could add an eventlistener to the image of which you want to display the blob, or use this.onLoad to add the eventlistener.